# FTP php отображение списка названия файлов

Tags: php, ftp

пытаюсь сделать отображение файлов с FTP сервера, но при разных вариациях, примерно одно и тоже сообщение bool(false).

```
 <?php

 $ftp_server = "00.000.000.000"; //ip adress
 $port = "0000";
 $ftp_user = "00";
 $ftp_pass = "000000";

 // установить соединение или выйти
 $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $port) or die("No connected $ftp_server"); 
 // попытка входа
 if (@ftp_login($conn_id,  $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
     echo "Connect $ftp_server name $ftp_user\n";
 } else {
     echo "No name $ftp_user\n";
 }
 echo "<br/>";
 ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
  // получение списка файлов директори /
 $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
 // вывод $contents
 var_dump($contents);
 // закрытие соединения
 ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас коннект не проходит. А так как вы соединяетесь принудительно "забив" на ошибки ( `@`ftp_login ) - вы этого даже не видите.

Comment: Ну, так-то ошибок нет, выводит нормально данные и подключается.